# Why is points to path tool connecting the start and ending points?

Tags: qgis, vector, points-to-line

The PointsToPath tool is connecting the start point to the end point.  I'm new to QGIS. I'm using an older version - 3.4.5. I have manually entered in the points in as a scratch layer. I export as a shapefile. Points to path tool connects the dots but it is also connecting the start and end dots. I don't want it to do that.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot showing the points, the line, and if available, the attributes you use to create the line on.